# Elliptic cylinder: axis vs semi-axis

Tags: geometry

I am staring at a linear algebra question:

Consider an Elyptical cilinder of axis Oz and semi axis a and b, height h (...)

What does the terms axis and semi axis mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

An elliptic cylinder looks like the one in the picture below

Its equation in a three dimensional reference system $Oxyz$ is, for instance
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

$$..$$

[image]